# Scala - identifier expected but '=>' found

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm writing an endpoint in a play scala application that makes a request to spotify, searching across `track`, `album` and `artist` types. I want to make over them and transform the string's into `Future`'s of the calls.

This is my code:

```
def index = Action.async { implicit request =>
  val futures = List("track", "album", "artist")
    .map { type => performSearch("q" -> param(request, "q"), "type" -> type) }

  Future.sequence(futures).onComplete {
    Ok
  }
}

private def performSearch(criteria: (String, String)): Future = {
  ws.url("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search")
    .withQueryString(criteria)
    .get()
}

private def param(request: Request[AnyContent], name: String): String = {
  request.queryString.get(name).flatMap(_.headOption).getOrElse("")
}
```

However I'm getting the error in my map of:

`identifier expected but '=>' found
// .map { type => performSearch("q" -> param(request, "q"), "type" -> type) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` is a keyword. Pick something else or put it inside `:

```
    .map { `type` => performSearch("q" -> param(request, "q"), "type" -> `type`) }
```